# Find a set of values to find maximum possible sets from a list of sets

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph, tree

SET =[a,b,c,d,e,1,2,3,4,5]

ELEMENTS=a,b,c....4,5

The **SET** can have minimum of **1** **ELEMENT** and maximum of **10**. First five **ELEMENTS** of **SETS** belongs to group "**A**" and rest with Group "**B**".
Problem statement:
Assume we have 500 **SETS** in a list. We have to select any number of **sets** from that list. Based on those selection, we will get **UNIQUE ELEMENTS** from all selected sets.
Now from all of those unique elements, we need to find out combination of **ELEMENTS** from which we can form maximum numbers of **SETS** from selected **SETS**.

I need an Algorithm to perform above task with least complexity.

Comment: Please show us some effort here.

Comment: so what i am doing is : i am getting the unique elements with their count of repetition. Then starting with max used element, finding the sets using it, then from those sets i am again finding the max used element and repeating the same cycle. At the same time i am removing the sets which are not using that maximum used element.

Comment: Please post CODE!!! Most of us are professional developer who can read code faster than strange requirements.

Comment: This can be formulated as a Linear Programming problem. Can you solve it from this point?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Here i am just asking for the right approach not the code!!

Comment: @Trifon Its done now, thanks buddy

Comment: @vishusrivastava please post the solution that you have found with code, so that it would be useful for future readers as well.